# I got this error: "State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback..." when i make a change in my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The sentence that i pasted in the tittle is what i got from my code, im triying to make a change over the state in an array , using hooks, this is my code.

```
export default function card(){
 let array = [true,false]

    const [change, setChange]=useState(array)


    function toggleIcon() {
        setChange(
            ...change,
            change[0]=!change[0]
        )
 console.log(change)
     }
return(
</Fragment>
    { change[0] ? (<p>hi</p>): (<p>bye</p>)}
</Fragment>
)

}
```

whit this i got the firts change, i change hi to bye... but when i click it again, y got this error MyContracts.js:18

> Uncaught TypeError: change is not iterable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are destructuring wrongly , try below code where you dont have to destructure but still if you want to try there is commented code.

```
function toggleIcon() {
        //let newState = [...change];
        //newState[0] = !change[0];
        //setChange(newState);

        change[0]=!change[0]
        setChange(change);
        console.log(change)
     }
```